# Trying to insert column of data into mySQL table

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I am using a select statement with a join to try and insert a column into a mySQL database table.

My code:

```
insert into trips_last_arrival_time(start_time)
select min_arrival_time.start_time
from min_arrival_time 
            inner join trips_last_arrival_time 
            on min_arrival_time.trip_id = trips_last_arrival_time.trip_id;
```

I am getting :

```
[Err] 1364 - Field 'trip_id' doesn't have a default value
trip_id is the primary key of both tables.
```

The start_time column is blank, not filled with nulls.

I've tried an UPDATE clause too

```
update trips_last_arrival_time
set trips_last_arrival_time.start_time  = (
select start_time from min_arrival_time )
where exists(
select trip_id from trips_last_arrival_time
where trips_last_arrival_time.trip_id = min_arrival_time.trip_id)
```

And there's a column trip_id in the table min_arrival_time (in fact it's the primary key of both tables!)
But this UPDATE clause gives me:

```
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'min_arrival_time.trip_id' in 'where clause'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert on an existing row (it exists because you have tried to SELECT it).  Regardless of whether `trip_id` has a default value, this is not the correct operation.  You need to do an UPDATE.

For your update, I'm pretty sure you need to do this:

```
UPDATE trips_last_arrival_time AS t, min_arrival_time AS m
    SET t.start_time = m.start_time
    WHERE t.trip_id = m.trip_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems.

In your first update query, the problem is that trip_id is a primary key, but does not get a default value.  This should be declared as auto_increment so you can insert new values easily.  The create table statement should be something like:

```
 trip_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 . . .
 primary key (trip_id)
```

You can fix this with an alter table statement, something like:

```
ALTER TABLE trips_last_arrival_time CHANGE trip_id trip_id UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

The problem with your update statement is different.  Formatted so I can read it:

```
update trips_last_arrival_time
    set trips_last_arrival_time.start_time = (
        select start_time from min_arrival_time )
    where exists(select trip_id
                 from trips_last_arrival_time
                 where trips_last_arrival_time.trip_id = min_arrival_time.trip_id
                )
```

The WHERE clause is referring to a table, min_arrival_time, that is not in the FROM clause and not in the outer query.  Instead, it is in another subquery.  This reference is out-of-context, which is causing your error.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for the insight. I'm going to test out some modifications to this based on your comments and i'll get back to you. I appreciate the insight as to why the update failed.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have set `trip_id` as the Primary Key of table `trips_last_arrival_time` which cannot be `null` and doesn't have default value. Do you manually generate your own `trip_id`? If not, make your `trip_id` column `AUTO_INCREMENT`ed so everytime you insert new records, the server automatically generates `trip_id` for you. Make sure that if set it to `AUTOINCREMNT` the column, its datatype should be `int`.

```
ALTER TABLE trips_last_arrival_time CHANGE trip_id UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Your update query look complicated, try simplying it a little better

```
UPDATE trips_last_arrival_time a 
            INNER JOIN min_arrival_time b
                ON a.trip_id = b.trip_id
SET     a.start_time  = b.start_time
```